# How can I get a full list of software installed on a non-functioning system, from its disk mounted on a new one?

Tags: migration

My motherboard suddenly died, but it was an old machine(running natty). So I put together a new Ubuntu system with a clean 14.04 install (same username) and mounted the old drive (with the full filesystem) as secondary device.

How can I get a full list of software installed on the old machine, from its disk mounted on the new one?

Comment: Sure, mount the hard drive, chroot into the system, and use `dpkg --get-selections`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the old drive, e.g. under `/mnt/old` and then do:

```
 dpkg --root-dir /mnt/old --get-selections | grep -F ' install' ' | cut -f 1
```

`dpkg` has facilities built-in to install/list/de-install on a filesystem not based directly under `/`.

Comment: syntax was a bit different on my case, but this is the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot via a linux Live, Then chroot to old linux, then:

```
dpkg -l "*" |grep ^ii |awk {'print $2'}
```